# Given $x^{p^2} = 1, x^p = y^p, yxy^{-1}=x^{p+1}$, show that $(yx^{-1})^p=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

> Suppose $p$ is an odd prime. Given $x^{p^2} = 1, x^p = y^p, yxy^{-1}=x^{p+1}$, show that $(yx^{-1})^p=1$, where $1$ is the identity.

I know that the conjugate of power is the power of conjugate, so $yx^{k}y^{-1} = (x^{p+1})^{k}$, and used this to obtain $yx^{-1} = x^{-p-1} y$, which will allow me to switch $y$ and $x^{-1}$ in each $yx^{-1}$. However, I still cannot figure out where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to whether $(yx^{-1})^p$ is a relator for the group given by the presentation $$\langle x,y\mid x^{p^2}, x^p=y^p, yxy^{-1}=x^{p+1}\rangle.$$

Comment: [There is no algorithm for this type of question.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups)

Comment: Eventhough there already is a solution, I'd like to share my way here. I tend to see those conjugation identities (such as $yxy^{-1}=x^{p+1}$ in your example) as "what happens when one variable goes through another". Here, I would read "$yx=x^{p+1}y$" as "when $y$ goes through $x$ from left to right, it changes it to $x^{p+1}$, _or rather multiplies its degree by $p+1$_". That way, I would end up with a solution similar to that of Kenny Lau

Comment: @Shaun You frequently post this comment on questions involving particular presentations. I don't think it's as useful as you think. While it's true there is no general algorithm, the vast majority of presentations involved in these questions come from exercises in books, etc., and are "easy" to deal with for anyone with a bit of experience. My suggestion would be to only mention this fact if there seems to be evidence that the presentation is "hard".

Comment: Here's a perhaps silly analogy: there is no algorithm for mathematical questions in general, but to go around posting this fact on every question would be a bit pointless.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @verret. I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$yx^k = x^{k(p+1)}y$, so $y^a x^k = x^{k(p+1)^a} y^a$, so:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(yx^{-1})^p
&=& y x^{-1} y x^{-1} y x^{-1} \cdots yx^{-1} \\
&=& x^{-(p+1)}y^2 x^{-1} y x^{-1} \cdots yx^{-1} \\
&=& x^{-(p+1)-(p+1)^2} y^3 x^{-1} \cdots yx^{-1} \\
&=& \cdots \\
&=& x^{-(p+1)-(p+1)^2-\cdots-(p+1)^{p-1}} y^p \\
&=& x^{-(p+1)-(2p+1)-\cdots-((p-1)p+1)} x^p \\
&=& x^{-\frac{(p-1)p}2 p - p} x^p \\
&=& x^{-\frac{(p-1)}2 p^2} \\
&=& 1 \\
\end{array}$$

where $x^{(p+1)^n} = x^{1+np+O(p^2)} = x^{1+np}$ because $x^{p^2}=1$.

Answer (score 3):

From $yxy^{-1} = x^{p+1}$ it follows that $yx^{-1}y^{-1} = (x^{p+1})^{-1}$, so $yx^{-1} = x^{-p-1}y$. We can now prove by an easy induction on $k$ that
$$
(yx^{-1})^k = x^{-p(1+2+\ldots+k)-k}y^k.
$$
For $k=p$, we obtain
$$
(yx^{-1})^p = x^{-p(1+2+\ldots+p)-p}y^p = x^{-p}y^p = 1
$$
since $p(1+2+\ldots+p) = p \cdot \frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ is a multiple of $p^2$.